Error when configuring the filter in Xdebug
When generating code coverage through Xdebug (PHP), it always asks me to configure the filter, however when editing phpunit.xml, it tells me that filter is an unexpected element.
Current:
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true" stopOnFailure="false">
    <coverage>
        <report>
            <text outputFile="coverage.txt"></text> <!-- Salida en consola a un archivo 'coverage.txt' -->
            <clover outputFile="coverage.xml"></clover> <!-- Informe XML de cobertura a 'coverage.xml' -->
        </report>
    </coverage>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Trabajo Final">
            <directory>Pruebas Unitarias</directory> <!-- Directorio con tus pruebas unitarias -->
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>


Problem:
 Line 7:
Element 'filter': This element is not expected.


Where do I configure the filter?
I already tried every thing I could without breaking it again.

Which PHPUnit version are you using? Is this the entire phpunit.xml?

You don't even have the word "filter" in your XML code, so you must be editing the wrong file. Beware that in some cases projects distribute a template which PHPUnit doesn't read, it's just used to generate the file that PHPUnit does read. Also, how do you invoke the phpunit command? Is it possible that it's a wrapper script that adds its own parameters?
